# How to combine two SQL queries where queries are joined by union

Tags: db2

Can anyone please help me in writing a single query joining these two queries.
I am using IBM DB2.

```
(SELECT 
  TABLE1.COLS,TBLE2.COLS,TABLE3.COLS 
 FROM 
  TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3,TABLE_PROB  
 WHERE 
  TABLE_PROB.COL=TABLE1.COL,OTHER_CLAUSE ) 
UNION      
(SELECT 
  TABLE1.COLS,TBLE2.COLS,TABLE3.COLS 
 FROM 
  TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3,TABLE_PROB1  
 WHERE TABLE_PROB1.COL=TABLE1.COL,OTHER_CLAUSE )
```

The two queries before and after `union` are same except that instead of "TABLE_PROB" it is changed to "TABLE_PROB1". There are no columns is to be selected from both the tables, they are only used to filter in the `where` clause.

Can anyone tell me how to combine both into a single query.

This query can be considered for the following scenario.
 There are few employee details table which contains details of all employees. 
   "TABLE_PROB" contains list of contract employees and "TABLE_PROB1" contains list of permanent employees. I need to get the details of both the contract and not contract employees based on few criteria.

Since the query has big Whereclause and select clause firing two queries by using union,increases the cost of the query. So I need to merge it by making a single query.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Is anything wrong with the query you posted?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes.. Since the select Queries and the where Clause used are so big, if I execute the almost same query 2 times by using Union it increases the cost. Since the change is very small for both the queries I need to merge it as a single query. Please do not vote down for unnecessary reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @mustaccio  Yes.. Since the select Queries and the where Clause used are so big, if I execute the almost same query 2 times by using Union it increases the cost. Since the change is very small for both the queries I need to merge it as a single query. Please do not vote down for unnecessary reasons. Thanks. –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot avoid the `UNION` because you still have to access both `TABLE_PROB` and `TABLE_PROB1`. Depending on your DB2 version, platform, and the system configuration this might perform a bit better:

```
 SELECT 
  TABLE1.COLS,TBLE2.COLS,TABLE3.COLS 
 FROM 
  TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3 
 WHERE 
  OTHER_CLAUSE 
  AND
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM TABLE_PROB
    WHERE COL=TABLE1.COL
    UNION
    SELECT 1 
    FROM TABLE_PROB1
    WHERE COL=TABLE1.COL
  )
```

Depending on the contents of TABLE_PROB.COL and TABLE_PROB1.COL `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` might also prove beneficial.